# What's the best way to query a column to see if it contains a particular number? The column is varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with a column that includes a handful of numbers delimited by a  comma. I need to select * rows that include a particular value. I am using SQL Server and C# so it can be in SQL or LINQ.

The data in my channels column (varchar) looks something like this: 1,5,8,22,27,33

My Media table looks like this:

```
MediaID MediaName MediaDate ChannelIDs
------- --------- --------- ----------
1 | The Cow Jumped Over The Moon | 01/18/2015 | 1,5,8,22,27,33
2 | The Cat In The Hat | 01/18/2015 | 2,4,9,25,28,31
3 | Robin Hood The Thief | 01/18/2015 | 3,5,6,9,22,33
4 | Jingle Bells Batman Smells | 01/18/2015 | 6,7,9,24,25,32
5 | Up The River Down The River | 01/18/2015 | 5,6,10,25,26,33
```

etc...

My Channels Table looks like this:

```
ChannelID ChannelName
--------- -----------
1 Animals
2 Television
3 Movies
4 Nursery Rhymes
5 Holidays
```

etc...

Each row of Media could contain multiple channels.

Should I be using a contains search like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Media WHERE CONTAINS (Channels,'22')
```

This would require me to full-text index this column but I don't really want to include this column in my full-text index.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Gordon is right but I want to call it out here too: STOP STORING COMMA-SEPARATED LISTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should fix your data format so you are not storing numbers as comma-delimited strings.  SQL has a great data structure for lists, it is called a table not a string.  In particular, you want a junction table with one row per "media" entity and id.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with a particular data structure.  If so, you can use like:

```
where ','+channels+',' like '%,22,%'
```

Note:  this cannot take advantage of regular indexes, so performance will not be good.  Fix the data structure if you have a large table and need better performance.

Comment: thx for the advice. I guess I should convert this over and make a junction table huh?

Comment: @Maddhacker24 . . . Yes.